# Create language modal(dialog)

Tags: 8, forms, blocks, ajax

I'm trying to create a language modal for Drupal 8.

I only want to show the modal if:

- Language paramater is not present in URL
- Language cookie is set by previous selection.

I don't really know what the best method is to create this.
I started by creating a hidden ajax button which gets clicked by custom js if the language parameter is not present in the URL and the language cookie is not set:

```
namespace Drupal\dms_theme\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\OpenModalDialogCommand;
use Drupal\lang_dropdown\Form\LanguageDropdownForm;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\Core\Language\Language;

/**
 * Class LangswitchModal.
 *
 * @package Drupal\dms_theme\Form
 */
class LangswitchModal extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'dms_theme_langswitch';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';

    $form['actions']['#type']  = 'actions';
    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type'  => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Switch language'),
      '#ajax'  => [
        'callback' => '::open_modal',
      ],
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  }

  public function open_modal(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Get active domain
    $domain_negotiator = \Drupal::service('domain.negotiator');

    $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\dms_theme\Form\LangswitchForm');

    // Build array
    $build = [];

    $build[] = [
      '#theme' => 'langswitch_modal',
      '#title' => 'Welcome',
      '#form' => render($form),
    ];

    $render  = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($build);

    // Dialog
    $options = [
      'dialogClass' => 'popup-languageswitcher-modal',
      'width'       => '100%',
    ];

    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand(NULL, $render, $options));

    return $response;
  }
}
```

The modal is opened correctly and the content and form is printed.

Logic of the form:

```
namespace Drupal\dms_theme\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\OpenModalDialogCommand;
use Drupal\lang_dropdown\Form\LanguageDropdownForm;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\Core\Language\Language;

/**
 * Class LangswitchForm.
 *
 * @package Drupal\dms_theme\Form
 */
class LangswitchForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'dms_theme_langswitchform';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Service
    $domain_negotiator = \Drupal::service('domain.negotiator');

    // Language options
    $language_options = [];
    foreach(domain_locale_custom_get_domains_languages()[$domain_negotiator->getActiveId()] as $domain_language) {
      $language_options[$domain_language->getId()] = $domain_language->getName();
    }

    $form['languages'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Please indicate from which location you are connecting:'),
      '#options' => $language_options,
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];

    $form['actions'] = [];
    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Submit button'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }



  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  }
}
```

Now i can't submit the form correctly. It redirects to urls like /form_action_p_pvdeGsVG5zNF_XLGPTvYSKCf43t8qZYSwcfZl2uzM.

I geuss this is caused by the ajax callback url, which is used by some form parameters. But don't really know how to solve this.

Thnx.

Other question:
What are in general the best practice to show a language modal.
If language is not is in URL? If language is not set in Cookie? Or the combination described above?

Answer (score 1):

You render early twice, which prevents that any attached metadata has a chance to get into the response. You can try without rendering or if you need to render, then attach the metadata to the response like in this example:

[ModalRenderer::renderResponse](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21MainContent%21ModalRenderer.php/function/ModalRenderer%3A%3ArenderResponse/8.4.x)

```
  public function renderResponse(array $main_content, Request $request, RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();

    // First render the main content, because it might provide a title.
    $content = drupal_render_root($main_content);

    // Attach the library necessary for using the OpenModalDialogCommand and set
    // the attachments for this Ajax response.
    $main_content['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
    $response->setAttachments($main_content['#attached']);

    // If the main content doesn't provide a title, use the title resolver.
    $title = isset($main_content['#title']) ? $main_content['#title'] : $this->titleResolver->getTitle($request, $route_match->getRouteObject());

    // Determine the title: use the title provided by the main content if any,
    // otherwise get it from the routing information.
    $options = $request->request->get('dialogOptions', []);

    $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand($title, $content, $options));
    return $response;
  }
```

Additional to the example you might need to add the attachments of the form too:

```
$response->addAttachments($form['#attached']);
```

---

"Other question: What are in general the best practice to show a language modal. If language is not is in URL? If language is not set in Cookie? Or the combination described above?"

There is also a server side approach. You can add some kind of overlay with the form before you deliver the page.